# Azure Cosmos db and functions javascript sdk - how to read document async?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, apollo, apollo-server

I have the following code in an apollo resolver:

```
Mutation: {
    addChannel: (root, args) => {
      client.readDocument("website", {}, (x) => {
        return { id: "Test", name: "Test Channel " + args.name }
      });
    },
```

where client is a document client:

```
var DocumentClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;
```

When it's called I'd like to wait on client.readDocument to finish and give me a return value that I will return (the example above is super simple and won't do that)

The problem I have is readDocument does something asynchronously in the background but the function isn'ta sync so I can't await it, so the function immediately falls through before the callback has a chance to finish. After the return data is sent (which is undefined) the callback function (x)=>{...} occurs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you move towards the v2 version of the Javascript API: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js

That way you can use the fluent path to the `items` and use `const { body: readDoc } = await item.read();` to read an item async.

You can find multiple samples on how this is done [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/master/samples/ItemManagement/app.js#L69)

Answer (score 2):

Three solutions I can think of here (which to use will depend on your exact situation):

1. v2 of the Cosmos DB API has async/await support so you can use that instead of the callback.
2. Wrap the callback code in a promise and await the promise.
3. Use a non-async Azure Function and return the result with `context.done(result)` at the end of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of your code doesn't fit with the callback model that `readDocument` follows therefore you have no mechanism to pass the document back out from `addChannel`.

Presuming you don't need to do any pre-processing to the document beforehand, you could use a combination of promises and the `async` / `await` syntax e.g.

```
addChannel: (root, arg) => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    client.readDocument("website", {}, (err, x) => 
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(x)
    )
  );
}
```

Then to "wait" on the document before executing other code

```
const doc = await obj.addChannel(...);
// use doc
```

*Note - `await` can only be used within a function marked as `async`*